# Is there a way to force add kiosk apps via the command line (vt2) on a chromebook?

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I need to find a way to force add or just add in general kiosk apps (they are zip files) to my chromebook. i dont have access to a google admin console (which is how you would add them) so i need a alternative way either by vt2/command line/bash shell or how ever other way.

Cant really try anything other then google admin console. I would know where to start in vt2 either.